# Python OpenCV "ImportError: undefined Symbol" or Memory Access Error

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opensuse, undefined-symbol

I'm using OpenSUSE 13.1 64-bit on an Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E145.
I tryed to play a bit around with Python(2.7) and Python-OpenCV(2.4). Both is installed by using YAST.
When i start the Python-Interactive-Mode (by typing "python") and try to "import cv" there are 2 things that happen:

case 1: "import cv" --> End's up with:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv23adaptiveBilateralFilterERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddNS_6Point_IiEEi`

case 2: "import cv2" --> End's up with:

> MemoryAccessError

and the interactive mode shutdown and i'm back at the normal commandline.

Have anyone any idea how can i solve this problem?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a prompt answer (nor a direct one). I had the same issue and (re)installing various dependencies didn't help either.

Ultimately, I cloned (from git) and compiled opencv (which includes the cv2.so library) from scratch, replaced the old cv2.so library and got it to work.

Here is the git repo: `https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git`